# My object counter for multiple constructors isn't giving me the right output

Tags: java, object, constructor, counter

My program looks like this -

```
package sysutilities;

public class Name {

// Declaring Instance Variables/////////////////////////////////////////////
String first;
String middle;
String last;
String nick;
char sep;

private static int nameObjsCount = 0;

// Verifying the validity of a separator////////////////////////////////////
private boolean validSeparator(char a) {

    if (a == ',' || a == '-' || a == '#') {
        return true;
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }
}

// Name constructor used to assign certain values to the instance variables/
public Name() {

    this.first = "NOFIRSTNAME";
    this.middle = "NOMIDDLENAME";
    this.last = "NOLASTNAME";
    this.sep = '#';

    nameObjsCount++;
}

// Name constructor with two parameters used to assign first and last name//
public Name(String first, String last) {

    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
    this.middle = "";
    this.sep = ',';

    nameObjsCount++;
}

// Name constructor used to assign first, middle and last name//////////////
public Name(String first, String middle, String last) {

    this.first = first;
    this.middle = middle;
    this.last = last;
    this.sep = ',';

    nameObjsCount++;

}

// Name constructor used to assign all values///////////////////////////////
public Name(String first, String middle, String last, char sep) {

    this.first = first;
    this.middle = middle;
    this.last = last;

    // If invalid separator, the separator defaults to comma////////////////
    boolean result = this.validSeparator(sep);

    if (result == false) {
        this.sep = ',';
    }

    else {
        this.sep = sep;
    }

    nameObjsCount++;

}

// Get and Set methods//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public String getFirstname() {

    return first;

}

public String getMiddlename() {

    return middle;

}

public String getLastname() {

    return last;

}

public void setNickname(String nick) {

    this.nick = nick;

}

public String getNickname(String nick) {

    if (nick == null) {
        nick = "";
    }

    return nick;

}

public void setSeparator(char sep) {

    Name data = new Name();

    boolean result = data.validSeparator(sep);

    if (result == true) {

        this.sep = sep;

    }

}

public char getSeparator(char sep) {

    return sep;

}

public boolean equals(Name input) {

    Name equation = new Name();

    equation.first = this.first;
    equation.middle = this.middle;
    equation.last = this.last;

    boolean firstTest = (equation.first).equals(input.first);
    boolean middleTest = (equation.middle).equals(input.middle);
    boolean lastTest = (equation.last).equals(input.last);

    if (firstTest == true && middleTest == true && lastTest == true) {

        return true;

    }

    else {
        return false;
    }

}

public String toString() {

    String output;

    if (nick != null) {

        if (this.middle.equals("")) {

            output = last + sep + first + "(" + nick + ")";

        }

        else {

            output = last + sep + first + sep + middle + "(" + nick + ")";

        }
    }

    else {

        if (this.middle.equals("")) {

            output = last + sep + first;

        }

        else {

            output = last + sep + first + sep + middle;

        }

    }

    return output;

}

// Check validity

public int compareTo(Name y) {

    int firstComp = this.first.compareTo(y.first);
    int middleComp = this.middle.compareTo(y.middle);
    int lastComp = this.last.compareTo(y.last);

    if (lastComp >= 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    else if (lastComp <= 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    else {

        if (firstComp >= 0) {
            return 1;
        }

        else if (firstComp <= 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        else {

            if (middleComp >= 0) {
                return 1;
            }

            else if (middleComp <= 0) {
                return -1;
            }

            else {

                return 0;

            }

        }

    }

}

public static int getNumberOfNameObjects() {

    return nameObjsCount;

}

// NORMALIZE//// Check middle
public static Name normalize(Name x, boolean test) {

    Name norm = x;
    norm.nick = null;

    if (test) {

        norm.first = norm.first.toUpperCase();
        norm.middle = norm.middle.toUpperCase();
        norm.last = norm.last.toUpperCase();

    }

    else {

        norm.first = norm.first.toLowerCase();
        norm.middle = norm.middle.toLowerCase();
        norm.last = norm.last.toLowerCase();

    }

    norm.sep = ',';

    return norm;

}
```

}

The program being run is this -

```
package tests;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

import sysutilities.Name;

public class PublicTests {
/* We use this string to prevent any hardcoding of results. */
/* The submit server uses a different value for TESTS_TAG   */
public static final String TESTS_TAG = "\nEndTest";

@Test
public void test1() {
    String answer = "";
    Name name1 = new Name("Claudia", "I.", "Smith");
    answer += name1 + "\n";

    Name name2 = new Name("Rachel", "I.", "Green", '#');
    answer += name2 + "\n";

    Name name3 = new Name("Joseph", "K.", "Falk");
    name3.setNickname("Joe");
    answer += name3 + "\n";

    Name name4 = new Name();
    answer += name4 + "\n";

    answer += "Same: " + name1.equals(name2) + "\n";

    answer += "Number of objects: " + Name.getNumberOfNameObjects();

    answer += TESTS_TAG;

    assertTrue(TestsSupport.isCorrect("pubTest1.txt", answer));
}
```

}

My problem is that my counter is apparently reading 5 when according to the program being run, it should read only 4.
I don't know why this is. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your other methods appear to be running `nameObjsCount++;` when it is not necessary. Note that creating temporary `Name` objects will increment the counter as well. Try making changes to these methods:

```
public void setSeparator(char sep) {
    //Name data = new Name();    //remove implicit nameObjsCount++
    boolean result = this.validSeparator(sep); //see below
    if (result == true) {
        this.sep = sep;
    }
}


public boolean equals(Name input) {
    // Name equation = new Name();    //remove implicit nameObjsCount++
    // equation.first = this.first;   //see below
    // equation.middle = this.middle;
    // equation.last = this.last;
    boolean firstTest = (this.first).equals(input.first);
    boolean middleTest = (this.middle).equals(input.middle);
    boolean lastTest = (this.last).equals(input.last);
    if (firstTest && middleTest && lastTest) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Note that there is really no reason to create these temp `Name`s, as your only using them for data and methods available to `this` instance. You could also make your `validSeparator()` method static since it does something generic, but that's a style issue.

Comment: It occurs in the equals method, but yes that would do it.

Comment: Of course. I had the suggestion up before the full source code was added, and made the mistake while editing from my phone.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating additional instances of `Name` in your `equals` and `setSeparator` methods.

You should change these methods to something more like

```
public void setSeparator(char sep) {

    if (validSeparator(sep)) {
        this.sep = sep;
    }

}
```

and

```
public boolean equals(Name input) {

    //Name equation = new Name();

    boolean firstTest = first.equals(input.first);
    boolean middleTest = middle.equals(input.middle);
    boolean lastTest = last.equals(input.last);

    return (firstTest && middleTest && lastTest);


}
```